# JDBC Confluent kafka Connector and Topic per schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

We recently started using Confluent Kafka-JDBC connector to import RDBMS data.

As part of default configuration settings, it seems that one Topic is created for every Table in the schema.

I would like to know if there is any way to

1. Create **Topic per schema** rather than every table. And if Topic per Schema is enabled then can Schema evolution (With Schema Registry) be supported on a table basis ?
2. If Topic per schema is not possible then are there any guidelines on how to manage hundred's or thousands of topics ? Considering that there will one to one mapping between number of tables to number of topics ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

> Create Topic per schema rather than every table.

No - it's either *n* tables -> *n* topics, or 1 query -> 1 topic.

> any guidelines on how to manage hundred's or thousands of topics ?

Adopt a standard naming pattern for them. Use topic-specific configuration as required.

Comment: Can Zookeeper manage Thousand's of topics if it holds metadata about schema registry ? Will the recovery from Zookeeper node failure take more time because of thousands of topics ? Are there any do's and don'ts around above issues ?